# Interior of closure of open set in topological space

Tags: general-topology

> If $U$ is an open set in a topological space, is it true that $U$ is the interior of the closure of itself?

If $U$ is open, it must be the interior of itself. But is it the interior of the closure of itself? In the closure, we include all points $x$ such that any open set containing $x$ also contains a point in $U$. In the interior of the closure, we take the union of all open sets contained in the closure.

Comment: If that were always so, the term "regular open set" would not have been invented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** What is the interior of the closure of $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite. Consider a punctured disc. That is consider $U=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}|0<\|x\|<1\}$.